# bootstrap data table and vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm using bootstrap data table and vue.js and
When i try to invoke DataTable function  after vue model creation, it doesn't work, why?
I tried $(app.$el).datatable() too, but did not work.
here is my code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all">First name</th>
      <th class="desktop">Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="ws in workschedule">
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#example',
                data: {
                    workschedule: []
        },
                created: function () {
                this.getSchedule();
            },
            methods: {
                getSchedule: function() {
                    var autourl =
                        'get.aspx?op=json&table=StoreUserWorkSchedule&qd=storeuserworkschedule' + appendTime();
                    this.$http.get(autourl)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            this.workschedule = response.data;
                        });
                }
            }
            });
            $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `$el` property in the created hook. `$el` is available after the vue instance is mounted i.e in the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) hook.

So invoke the datatable function in the mounted hook

```
mounted: function() {    
   this.$el.DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry there was a problem in my question, I edited it, I invoke datatable function in the end of vue model creation, by the way , I tried to inovke it in mount hook , but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

finally, the watch option solved it

```
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#example',
                data: {
                    workschedule: []
                },
                created: function () {
                    this.getSchedule();
                },
                watch: {
                    workschedule: function (newData) {
                        $('#example').DataTable({
                            responsive: true
                        });
                    }
            },
            methods: {
                getSchedule: function() {
                    var autourl =
                        'get.aspx?op=json&table=StoreUserWorkSchedule&qd=storeuserworkschedule' + appendTime();
                    this.$http.get(autourl)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            this.workschedule = response.data;
                        });
                }
            }
            });
```